# MySql - how to make left joining table and get top 1 order by date desc from table?

Tags: mysql

Good day.

For example have 2 table - `Example1` and `Example2`

Structure table `Example1`:

```
idn(int 11)
username(int 11)
date(datetime)
```

Rows:

```
idn      username     date

10       test        01-12-2013 00:00
```

Structure table `Example2`:

```
idn(int 11)
val(int 11)
date(datetime)
```

Rows:

```
idn   val     date
10    100   01-12-2013 12:00
10    120   02-12-2013 12:00
10    110   02-12-2013 15:00
10    150   05-12-2013 12:00
10    90    08-12-2013 12:00
```

I want get `username` and him last `val`(from table `Example2`).

In result it should be:

```
username  val
test      90
```

For get it i use:

```
SELECT 
  ex1.username, 
  ex2.val 
FROM Example1 ex1
left joing Example2 as ex2 on ex2.idn = ex1.idn
```

But how get last value `val` in it query ?

**Tell me please how to make it?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your explanation, please try this:

```
SELECT ex1.username,
       ex2.val
FROM Example1 AS ex1
LEFT JOIN Example2 AS ex2 ON ex1.idn = ex2.idn
WHERE ex1.username = 'test'
ORDER BY ex2.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: me need get last value on input `date` in table `Example2` and `order by` can not use input second table (`Example2`). can use order by ex2.date in `left join` ?

Comment: What do you mean by last value of input?

Comment: value `val` in table `Example2` on last `date` (in my example it was `90`). in your answer i can not use `ORDER BY ex2.date DESC` in main sql, becose he will be have other order by(he will be have `order by username`)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not following.  If you want to pull out the record that has a `val` of `90`, you have no choice but to `ORDER BY ex2.date DESC`.  How else are you going to pull out the most recent record from the `Example2` table?  I did modify my query though and added a `WHERE` clause to limit which username the query is searching for. Perhaps that's what you meant.

Comment: no-no your query right, but can not use `order by date` in main sql?
bocose my main query will be `SELECT ex1.username, ex2.val FROM Example1 ex1 ORDER by ex1.username`. and me need add to him `left join`. understand or may be see on example sqlfiddle?

Comment: Sure, if you can set up an sqlfiddle that may be helpful.  I'm just confused as to why you are ordering by username if you need the 'latest' item from your database which implies an order by date.

Answer (score 0):

please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb1d82/5/0)
I have 2 usernames in my example

```
SELECT 
  ex1.username, 
  (SELECT ex2.val FROM Example2 ex2
   WHERE ex2.idn = ex1.idn
   ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) as val
FROM Example1 ex1
ORDER BY ex1.username
```